# Remove string "Array" from print_r()'s output

Tags: php, arrays, string, formatting

How can I remove the string "Array" in the printout from `print_r()`?
I have tried using string replace, but it didn't work.

Example output:

```
    Array ( 
       [0] => Array (
               [id] => Classify318721363801824
               [classification] => 
                  Array ( 
                        [0] => Array ( 
                                    [Klasifikasi] => NonOpini 
                                    [Nilai] => 0.999946 ) 
                        [1] => Array ( 
                                    [Klasifikasi] => Opini 
                                    [Nilai] => 5.43418e-005 ) )
```

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for something like `var_dump` or `var_export`?

Comment: Can you explain why you WANT to do this?

Comment: Why didn't string replace work? What was your code for that? Did you not pass [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) _TRUE_ as the second argument, thereby causing it to output rather than return a string?

Comment: Are you trying to use `print_r()` for actual user facing output? Its purpose is debugging.

Comment: `i have try using string replace` *How* have you tried using it?  Please post your PHP code.  You might have had a misunderstanding on how it works and SO can certainly help there.

Comment: emm, i actually confused in complex array. simply, i just want to print something like this:
Classification: NonOpinion
  Score: 0.9
Classification: Opinion
  Score: 0.1
                                                                               I do tend to use for () instead of foreach ()?

Comment: @user2192076, it depends of what you want to get at the end. If just to remove some useless text - then use `print_r()` with return flag and replace whatever u want. If you need something more complex to do with array elements, then you should write a recursive function to walk through your array and handle with it.

Answer (score 2):

Set `return flag` (secont func arg) at `TRUE`  for `print_r()` function to return array print as string, than replace whatever you want using str_replace.

```
echo str_replace('Array','',print_r($arr,true));
```

I suppose you also want to replace unneeded new lines. Here's my own func to print arrays nicely.

```
function aprint($arr, $return = false) {
    $wrap = '<div style=" white-space:pre; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; height:200px; width:100px; overflow:auto; z-index:5000;">';
    $wrap = '<pre>';
    $txt = preg_replace('/(\[.+\])\s+=>\s+Array\s+\(/msiU','$1 => Array (', print_r($arr,true));

    if ($return) return  $wrap.$txt.'</pre>';
    else echo $wrap.$txt.'</pre>';
}
```

Comment: This is probably what the asker was trying to do. Unfortunately it's an indiscriminate replacement, so any array contents that contain "Array" will also be replaced. That's probably undesirable.

Comment: @Wiseguy, thanks for your notice. I've updated my func code to search for an Array string more strictly. It still can be tricked, by I think it isn't really serious issue. Anyway it can be upgraded even further if someone need it.

Comment: @DenisO. Your `preg_replace` line is not working for me. It has no effect on the formatting of an associative array.